# Why is this method being skipped when it is called correctly with no syntax errors?

Tags: java, methods, matrix

Here is the basic code for what is going on. I have a already prompted for the input of the number of rows and columns, which works. The problem is once the program reaches `"Enter the data..."` it prints it but completely ignores the call to `Matrix`. Inside of `Matrix` I prompt to enter a matrix using the scanner class as well. Also, I realize this has no end currently. Please help.

```
 case 1: 
           System.out.println("Enter the data for the first matrix.");

           //input needed
           MatrixOne = Matrix(Rows, Columns);
           System.out.println("+");
           System.out.println("Enter the data for the second matrix.");
           MatrixTwo = Matrix(Rows, Columns);
           int[][]Plus = Add(MatrixOne, MatrixTwo, Rows, Columns);
           Print(Rows, Columns, Plus);
           break;
```

Here is the method:

```
public static int [][] Matrix(int Rows, int Columns)
{
  int[][] NewMatrix = new int[Rows][Columns];
  for(int i=0; i<Rows; i++)
  {
     for(int j=0; j<Columns; j++)
     {
     System.out.println("HIIIIIIII");
        NewMatrix[i][j] = keyboard.nextInt ();
     }
  }
  return NewMatrix;
}
```

Here is the output currently:

```
Please choose an operation: Addition(1) or Subtract(2)1
How many Rows would you like your matrix to have?
2
How many Columns would you like your matrix to have?
2
Enter the data for the first matrix.
+
Enter the data for the second matrix.
= 
Please choose an operation: Addition(1) or Subtract(2)
```

This is what's above everything:

```
  int Rows=0;
  int Columns=0;

  int [][] MatrixOne;
  int [][] MatrixTwo;

  do{

     System.out.print("Please choose an operation: Addition(1) or Subtract(2)");
     operation = keyboard.nextInt();

     RowColumns(Rows, Columns);
```

And this is the method:

```
public static void RowColumns(int Rows, int Columns)
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("How many Rows would you like your matrix to have?");
  Rows = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("How many Columns would you like your matrix to have?");
  Columns = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

And `main`:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      String End; 
      int operation;

      int Rows = 0;
      int Columns = 0;

      int [][] MatrixOne;
      int [][] MatrixTwo;

      do{

         System.out.print("Please choose an operation: Addition(1) or Subtract(2)");
         operation = keyboard.nextInt();

         RowColumns(Rows, Columns);

       /////////////////READS INPUT AND DETERMINES TO ADD OR SUBTRACT//////////////////////////////////

         switch(operation)//Reads the value of the variable Operation. If Operation equals 1, the program will add the matrices,...
         //if Operation equals 2, the program will subtract the matrices, and if the Operation equals anything other than 1 or 2, the...
         //user will be prompted to enter either 1 or 2 again.
         {
            case 1: 
               System.out.println("Enter the data for the first matrix.");

               //input needed
               MatrixOne = Matrix(Rows, Columns);
               System.out.println("+");
               System.out.println("Enter the data for the second matrix.");
               MatrixTwo = Matrix(Rows, Columns);
               int[][]Plus = Add(MatrixOne, MatrixTwo, Rows, Columns);
               Print(Rows, Columns, Plus);
               break;
            case 2: 
               System.out.println("Enter the data for the first matrix.");
               MatrixOne = Matrix(Rows, Columns);
               System.out.println("-");
               System.out.println("Enter the data for the second matrix.");
               MatrixTwo = Matrix(Rows, Columns);
               int[][]Minus = Subtract(MatrixOne,MatrixTwo, Rows, Columns);
               Print(Rows, Columns, Minus);
               break;
            default: System.out.println("Please enter 1 to add the matrices or 2 to subtract them.");
         }//End of Switch
      }while(operation != 1 || operation != 2);
   }//End of main
```

Comment: There seems to still be a carriage return/new line character in your `Scanner`s buffer.  Try adding `keyboard.nextLine` after each `keyboard.nextInt`

Comment: In Java, please use camalCase for methods and PascalCase for classes.

Comment: Where are you reading in the values for rows and columns?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that MadProgrammer

Comment: Rows and Columns are in a seperate method and called above the cases

Comment: Like Marty said, it looks like they're both 0. Can you show the code so we can make sure the values are being changed by the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Matrix method, it won't the enter the loop if the Rows or Columns is zero; so maybe they may have a value of zero.

Comment: but they have a value of 2 once I input 2. Right?

Comment: try printing the i and j in the loops

Comment: So I changed the intilazed rows and columns to 2 and it ran. I still don't understand why though. Could you explain?

Comment: Show us the entire main method.

Comment: Are Rows and Columns variables global? If not, they will only be affected inside the method. And change your variables to camelcase

Comment: They are not global but they shouldn't need to be because they are used elsewhere

Comment: You have the non-global variables Columns and Rows initialized at 0 inside the main method, but you changed their values inside the method RowColumns. Their values will still be zero even if you called the RowColumns method because they are not global. Try printing the Rows and Columns variables inside the switch statement.

Comment: I placed it inside the switch and still the same result of Rows and Columns being zero happened. It printed zero

Comment: That's exactly my point. You could either make them global, make the RowColumns return something or just get the Rows and Columns inside the main method.

Answer (score 1):

Java is [`pass by value`](http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/passby.html).

In `RowColumns` function, you are `passing` two integers `by value` which means that, only their values are passed to the function, not the references. Because of that, actual references of those variables will not be affected. Therefore, after the `RowColumns(Rows, Columns)` call, `Rows` and `Columns` variables will remain same with their initial values (0, 0).

If you want to change the values of the variables inside of a function, then you should return them.

To do this, you can define a container for these two values:

```
public class Size {
    public int Rows;
    public int Columns;
}
```

Then you can initialize and use it as;

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {

    ...
    Size size = new Size();

    ...
    size = RowColumns(size);
    ...
}

public Size RowColumns(Size size)
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("How many Rows would you like your matrix to have?");
  size.Rows = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("How many Columns would you like your matrix to have?");
  size.Columns = keyboard.nextInt();
  return size;
}
```

Comment: And this is why seeing all the code in play is important.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually is calling the `Matrix` method perfectly fine, the issue is with your `RowColumns` method. Your `RowColumns` method isn't actually setting the variables you think it is, so when your `Matrix` method is called the Row and Columns variables passed to it are zero.

Let me break down what exactly is happening. In java integers are passed by value, not by reference. This means that when you call `RowColumns(Row, Columns);` whats really happening is the actual value of Row and Columns are taken and sent off to the RowColumns method, not the variables themselves. Effectively this is happening `RowColumns(0, 0);`

Despite the parameters in your `RowColumns` method having the same name they are not the same variable. Here is another way to look at your code.

```
int Rows1=0;
int Columns1=0;
RowColumns(Rows1, Columns1);
```

and your `RowColumns` method

```
public static void RowColumns(int Rows2, int Columns2)
{
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("How many Rows would you like your matrix to have?");
   Rows2 = keyboard.nextInt();

   System.out.println("How many Columns would you like your matrix to have?");
   Columns2 = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

When `RowColumns` gets called `Rows2` is set equal to `Rows1` and `Columns2` is set equal to `Columns1`, notice how your `RowColumns` doesn't actually effect `Rows1` and `Columns1`. In your code you have confused yourself by naming the parameters of `RowColumns` the same as the variables being passed to it, which means that while it looks like they are the same, they are in fact completely different.

One solution to this is to simply do away with the `RowColumns` method if you don't need it else where like this:

```
int Rows=0;
int Columns=0;

int [][] MatrixOne;
int [][] MatrixTwo;

do{

   System.out.print("Please choose an operation: Addition(1) or Subtract(2)");
   operation = keyboard.nextInt();

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("How many Rows would you like your matrix to have?");
   Rows = keyboard.nextInt();

   System.out.println("How many Columns would you like your matrix to have?");
   Columns = keyboard.nextInt();
```

This would accomplish the same thing but this time you would be using the `Rows` and `Columns` variables you want to.

If you want to keep the user input to its own method the most straight forward solution would be to create two separate methods, one to get the rows and one to get the columns, then have those methods return the value given by the user. Something like this:

```
int Rows=0;
int Columns=0;

int [][] MatrixOne;
int [][] MatrixTwo;

do{

   System.out.print("Please choose an operation: Addition(1) or Subtract(2)");
   operation = keyboard.nextInt();

   Rows = getRows();
   Columns = getColumns();
```

and the two methods would look something like this:

```
public static int getRows()
{
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("How many Rows would you like your matrix to have?");
   return keyboard.nextInt();
}

public static int getColumns()
{
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("How many Columns would you like your matrix to have?");
   return keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

There are all kinds of ways to solve this problem, I just gave the two most straight forward ones. Hope this sufficiently answers your question!